# ASP.NET Blank Website Template in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Did Microsoft removed the ASP.NET Website template - referring to the blank ASP.NET website not the empty ASP.NET website?

I search ASP.NET's official website but can't find documentation regarding that particular template.

I need to use that specific template for school. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select `New Website`, one of the choices is `ASP.NET Empty Website` ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377605.aspx)).

Comment: Just add it yourself. Right-mouse click on the project, select `Add New Item` and from the list of templates select 'WebForm'. Name it 'default' and you're done.

Comment: Thank you. Am still learning the abbreviations used on this website forum... (ref) is reference.